# Imprimir apenas clicando em botão da página

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Há uma forma de colocar o conteúdo da página para imprimir apenas pelo botão de crio na página?

**Eu tenho a função em `JS`**

```
function cont(){
    window.print();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onClick="cont();">click</button>
```

Há uma forma de já ir imprimir já quando clica no botão? sem precisar abrir aquele dialogo do navegador chrome mostrando as coisas de imprimir.

Se possível em js.

Comment: Você quer dizer imprimir direto para a impressora padrão?

Comment: Ou talves essas respostas possam de ajudar [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633386/how-to-skip-browser-default-print-preview-and-print-content-directly-to-printer ]

Comment: Imprimir direto para a impressora padrão já clicando no botao. Ex.: clicou no botao, imprimiu